# How to show contents of file from multiple servers - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I have looked and I can't quite seem to find what I am looking for.
I am almost there, all I want is a script to run on several servers which will go off and check the contents of one file and display the results.

This is what I have so far:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

$hostnames = 'server1','server2'
$searchtext = "Group*"

foreach ($hostname in $hostnames)
{
    $file = "\\$hostname\E$\test.htm"

    if (Test-Path $file)
    {
        if (Get-Content $file | Select-String $searchtext)
        {
            Write-host "$hostname $file"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$hostname Imaging not completed"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$hostname cannot read file: $file"
    }
}
```

This script is going off to the servers but I cannot get it to to tell me what is in that file on screen. I get this:

```
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
server1 \\server1\E$\test.htm
server2 \\server2\E$\test.htm
```

Can anyone advise how I swap out the file path for the actual contents that it reads?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is that all you see on the screen? I dont see something wrong with your code, you're providing a valid UNC path.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the filename to a non-existant filename and it still gives the exact same error. Maybe it is UNC related

Comment: Which error? We don't see one in your question

Comment: Sounds like you want to replace `Write-host "$hostname $file"` with `Write-host "$hostname $(Get-Content $file | Select-String $searchtext |Out-String)"`

Comment: Sorry when I say error, I mean lack of feedback.

server1 \\server1\E$\test.htm
server2 \\server2\E$\test.htm

Comment: So you dont see any of those `Write-Host` statements in your console?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thats perfect! Works great now thank you!

Comment: As aside, I think you want the searchtext to be `$searchtext = "Group.*"`, because the pattern value is treated as a regular expression, not as wildcard

Answer (score 0):

The search string can be added to your script so that you can retrieve its results. This will enable you to see the contents of the file that match the chosen search string when you run the script.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

$hostnames = 'server1','server2'
$searchtext = "Group*"

foreach ($hostname in $hostnames)
{
    $file = "\\$hostname\E$\test.htm"

    if (Test-Path $file)
    {
        $result = Get-Content $file | Select-String $searchtext
        if ($result)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostname $file - Search string found: $searchtext"
            $result | Write-Output
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$hostname Imaging not completed"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$hostname cannot read file: $file"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in parallel over invoke-command as well.  But select-string's output is funny over invoke-command, unless you pick a property.

```
icm ar001,ar002,ar003 { select-string logfilepath c:\googleupdate.ini | select line }

Line                         PSComputerName RunspaceId
----                         -------------- ----------
LogFilePath=GoogleUpdate.log ar001          e411d83a-362f-42cb-9c84-b560bce44949
LogFilePath=GoogleUpdate.log ar002          g411d83a-362f-42cb-9c84-b560bce44949
LogFilePath=GoogleUpdate.log ar003          h411d83a-362f-42cb-9c84-b560bce44949
```